# VBA in Excel 2013, Loop through files where the wildcard applies to the subdirectory

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2013, dir

I have a MATLAB script that analyzes experimental results on a number of widgets my company makes, and finally exports the summarized data into a CSV file. I want to import all of these csv files into an Excel workbook so that I can compare the summarized results using a pivot table.

Each widget currently has its own directory, with a *Datasets* subdirectory that contains a *pivotData.csv* file. The directory structure looks something like the following:

1. C:\Path\To\Widgets

   - Widget_1\Datasets\pivotData.csv
   - Widget_2\Datasets\pivotData.csv
   - Widget_3\Datasets\pivotData.csv
   - Widget_3b\Datasets\pivotData.csv
   - Widget_4\Datasets\pivotData.csv

The master workbook, *pivotMaster.xlsm*, is in the main directory: *C:\Path\To\Widgets\pivotMaster.xlsm*

I am creating a macro in the master workbook that loops through each widget directory, and appends the data in the master workbook.

So far I have been able to put this code together, which was inspired by someone looping over various csv files in the same directory. I'm currently having trouble on using a wildcard for a directory name. The error is when I try to initialize Filename by concatenating the Path and subdirectory wildcard strings.

```
Sub test()
'DECLARE AND SET VARIABLES
Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim Filename As String
Dim Path As String
Path = "C:\Path\To\Widgets\"
Filename = Dir(Path & "Widget_*\Datasets\pivotData.csv")  %%% <-- I get an error on this line &&&
'--------------------------------------------
'OPEN EXCEL FILES

'Clear all the previous contents
Application.Run ("clearContents")

'Loop over all "pivotData.csv" files in Filename
 Do While Len(Filename) > 0  'IF NEXT FILE EXISTS THEN
    Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(Path & Filename)

'Notify User that Filename has opened
    MsgBox Filename & " has opened"  'OPTIONAL- CAN COMMENT OUT

'Move to first empty row below "A1"
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[1]C[0]"

'Import Data from Text file "Filename"
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        wbk, Destination:= _
        ActiveCell)
        .CommandType = 0
        .Name = "pivotData_1"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 850
        .TextFileStartRow = 2
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    Range("A1").Select
    wbk.Close True
    Filename = Dir
Loop
End Sub

Sub clearContents()
'
' clearContents Macro clears everything below the headers
'

'
    Rows("2:2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.clearContents
End Sub
```

Can anyone give me an idea of what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: You can't use wildcards (`*`) in a directory path element.

Answer (score 0):

This will get you folders in a folder, just keep drilling down until you find your workbooks.

```
Sub DrillDown()

Dim path As String
path = "C:\path\to"

Dim FileSystem As Object
Set FileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim SubFolder
For Each SubFolder In FileSystem.GetFolder(path).subfolders
 Debug.Print SubFolder

Next

End Sub
```

To go through looking for files -

```
Sub LookForFiles()
Dim filename As Variant
filename = Dir("C:\path\to\" & "*.csv")
    Do While filename <> ""
        Debug.Print filename
        filename = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```

So you could go through the directories until you find the directory name you expect, then look for the csv files and do what you want.